# How to fix multiple call fetch data in forEach() using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In react Hooks, I am trying to fetch data from the API array but in the Foreach function, the API call causes infinity.
How to fix this?

```
const [symbols, setSymbols] = useState([]);

getPortfolioSymbolList(portfolio_name).then(data => data.json()).then(res => {

   res.forEach((symbol_data)=>{
      fetchPrice(symbol_data.symbol).then(price => {
         setSymbols(price);

      });
          
   })
}

function fetchPrice(symbol){
    const price = fetch(`api_url`)
    .then(chart => chart.json())
    return price;
}
```

Here, call fetchPrice() causes in infinite.

Answer (score 0):

## Setting the state will always cause a rerender

What happens in your code is the request is made and then the data is set causing a rerender. Then because of the rerender the request is made again and sets the state again and causes the rerender again.

If you have a request for data you probably want to put a `React.useEffect` so it only requests once.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  /* your data request and data set */
}, []); // the [] will only fire on mount.
```

Answer (score 0):

Is is because your `setSymbols` call inside forEach makes component rerender (reload) - it means that all of your main component function is call again and again... `getPortfolioSymbolList` too. You have to use `useEffect` hook to resolve this problem. Your getPortfolioSymbolList() API call should be inside useEffect.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 0):

### PROBLEM

Your first symbol is updated in your API call, which triggers a re-render of the component calling the API call to go on an infinite loop.

### SOLUTION

1. Wrap your `API` in your `useEffect`. The function inside your useEffect will only be called once. [See useEffect docs here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)
2. You need to use `for await of` to loop asynchronously. `forEach` can't loop asynchronously. [See `for await of` docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of)
3. Update your symbols once all the data is collected.

```
function Symbols() {
  const [symbols, setSymbols] = useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchSymbols() {
      const portfolio = await getPortfolioSymbolList(portfolio_name);
      const jsonPortfolios = await data.json();

      const symbols = [];
      for await (let jsonPortfolio of jsonPortfolios) {
        const price = await fetchPrice(jsonPortfolio.symbol);
        symbols.push(price);
      }

      setSymbols(symbols);
    }

    fetchSymbols();
  }, []);

  return /** JSX **/
}
```